# What is Advent Software's Geneva?

Tags: software, investing

I've heard from Renaissance Technologies Corp. that there exists a software for investors which is called Advent Software's Geneva. Could anyone be able to explain to me what is this software exactly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Advent Geneva is a complex event processing platform, which employs the latest advancements in artificial intelligence and big data. It employs techniques derived from blockchain technology and cryptography to speed up trading strategies. Under the hood, it uses a fast in-memory database whose kernel sits on an FPGA, to meets its demands in Ultra (in caps) high-frequency trading. It has the ability to drive an electric car autonomously and land it on Mars, using sophisticated Machine Learning (in caps) models, and earns every dollar in Bitcoin through advertising and Deep Learning (in caps). It is also column-oriented and distributed and has reached 3 million downloads on the iTunes store, and Advent was funded by Andreessen Horowitz. And it was written by some obscure mathematician who spent his time studying the analytic properties of weak Ricci curvature bounds, I heard on Zerohedge that's how they're making all that money. It is a crowdsourced spoofing and quote spamming engine  that every Kaggle user swears by and Google has released an open source alternative to it. [insert uninterpretable but colorful Nanex diagram] More importantly, none of the above exists but Elon Musk has an idea to make this happen which makes it more valuable than something that exists anyway.

...is what I'd have liked to say. The truth is much less interesting.

Advent Geneva is simply a middle/back office platform that performs various fund accounting functions, especially PnL/NAV computation, cash/position reconciliation and investor reporting and generation of statements for fund LPs.

Most hedge fund administrators provide a superset of these services and perform these functions through Advent Geneva. This is especially the case with mid-size fund administrators that do not have the development resources to build their own software platform. So in fact most hedge funds that engage a third party administrator are using it indirectly. While standalone, the licensing fees associated with it are high, it usually comes down to a small number of basis points for a fund at self-sustaining mass.

Comment: So the geneva platform is clearly not available for little investor, right?

Comment: In fact, eventually, I'd like to become a hedge fund manager. I have the capabilities in maths to do that kind of things. So far I don't even know what's the relation between Ricci curvature bound and the stock market.I'll probably try to learn more about the subject. Thanks for you answer BTW, I appreciate.

Comment: ^It's generally not cost-effective unless you have >10M in AUM. Besides, generally the 'little investor' has no use case for Advent Geneva.

Comment: As long as you focus on studying Ricci curvature bounds you will certainly become a wealthy hedge fund millionaire. Also try and see if you can find patterns in the digits of pi. Secrets lie in those numbers and are prime for exploitation by talented mathematicians such as yourself.